# Cannot install packages, error: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, readonly

I already few days cannot install any packages, I getting this error:

```
dpkg: error: unable to access the dpkg database directory /var/lib/dpkg: Read-only file system
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I tried out answers from this questions:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/269856/dpkg-error-unable-to-access-dpkg-status-area-read-only-file-system
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/716915/dpkg-error-processing-packages-cannot-complete-install-desktop-gui-from-termina

But that didn't work.

My OS:

- Name: Endless 4.0.6; Build ID: 220427-214022
- Type: 64-bit
- GNOME version: 3.38.5
- Windowing system: X11

Drive:

- Partition Type: EFI System
- Contents: FAT (16-bit version) — Not Mounted

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This part of the error message explains exactly what the problem is:

```
/var/lib/dpkg: Read-only file system
```

You can't write anything to a filesysm that's mounted read-only.  You'll need to remount your filesystem that contains the path `/var/lib/dpkg` to be read-write.  Or, more to the point, determine why it is that the system panicked and flipped it to read-only mode, and fix the underlying problem.

Comment: A quick look at `dmesg` should give the reason for which the filesystem became read-only.